# Can header and footer be called from the base?

Tags: html, css, django

Currently my dilemma is I want the div in my base.html to be in my home_page.html but I need it around my header, main and footer.

This is my base.html

```
<div class="cover-container d-flex h-100 p-3 mx-auto flex-column">
    {# header #}

    {# /header #}
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    {# footer #}

    {# footer #}
</div>
```

And this is  my home_page that extends base.

```
{% extends "../base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load wagtailcore_tags wagtailimages_tags %}
{% block body_class %}Home{% endblock %}
{% block extra_css %}
    {# Override this in templates to add extra stylesheets #}

{% endblock %}
{% block extra_js %}
    {# Override this in templates to add extra javascript #}

{% endblock %}
{% block content %} {#    html stuff sits in here#}
        <main role="main" class="inner cover">

{% endblock %}
```

Is there a way to call on the header and footer specifically in the homepage.html?

Comment: What is the real problem you're trying to solve ? Why do you want this div to be in your home instead of being in the base ?

Comment: I only want this div to be on the home page and not all the pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I only want this div to be on the home page and not all the pages

I assume that what you mean here is that you only want this div to have this particular set of classes for the home page, and not for other pages (IOW, having a div with no classes or other classes is ok for the other pages).

If that's the case, the solution is simple: leave the div where it is, but wrap the div's classes into it's own block (with default - eventually empty - values), and override thsi block in the home page, ie:

base.html:

```
<div class="{% block page-css-class %}{% endblock %}">
    {# header #}

    {# /header #}
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    {# footer #}

    {# footer #}
</div>
```

and home.html

```
{% extends "../base.html" %}

{% block page-css-class %}cover-container d-flex h-100 p-3 mx-auto flex-column{% endblock %}

{# your remaining code here #}
```

Answer (score 0):

`extends` tag is used to inherit your parent template into the child template. It then looks for the`block` tags in your parent template and replaces it with the values of the child template.
`include` tags loads a template and renders with the current context. You probably want to use `{% include "footer.html" with my_context_variable=value %}` to pass additional context.You can read more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#include).

Comment: Does that take into consideration for the div page-specific around the footer and header?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned I would only use includes here as a last resort solution. The point of template inheritance is actually to avoid this kind of boilerplate, and most of the time there are better solutions.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I agree. I thought the questioner wanted to add the concerned divs only on specific pages along with the base template